# Creating multiple files from Vinyl stream with Through2

Tags: node.js, gulp, through2

I've been trying to figure this out by myself, but had no success yet. I don't even know how to start researching for this (though I've tried some Google searchs already, to no avail), so I decided to ask this question here.

Is it possible to return multiple Vinyl files from a Through2 Object Stream?

My use case is this: I receive an HTML file via stream. I want to isolate two different sections of the files (using jQuery) and return them in two separate HTML files. I can do it with a single section (and a single resulting HTML file), but I have absolutely no idea on how I would do generate two different files.

Can anyone give me a hand here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic approach is something like this:

1. Create as many output files from your input file as you need using the [`clone()`](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl#cloneopt) function.
2. Modify the [`.contents`](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl#contents) property of each file depending on what you want to do. Don't forget that this is a [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html), not a String.
3. Modify the [`.path`](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl#path) property of each file so your files don't overwrite each other. This is an absolute path so use something like [`path.parse()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_parse_pathstring) and [`path.join()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2) to make things easier.
4. Call `this.push()` from within the [`through2` transform function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/through2#transformfunction) for every file you have created.

Here's a quick example that splits a file `test.txt` into two equally large files `test1.txt` and `test2.txt`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var through = require('through2').obj;
var path = require('path');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('test.txt')
    .pipe(through(function(file, enc, cb) {
       var c = file.contents.toString();
       var f = path.parse(file.path);
       var file1 = file.clone();
       var file2 = file.clone();
       file1.contents = new Buffer(c.substring(0, c.length / 2));
       file2.contents = new Buffer(c.substring(c.length / 2));
       file1.path = path.join(f.dir, f.name + '1' + f.ext);
       file2.path = path.join(f.dir, f.name + '2' + f.ext);
       this.push(file1);
       this.push(file2);
       cb();
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('out'));
});
```

Comment: i didn't know there was a .clone funcion. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: 4 years later and your answer just put an end to many hours of googling for this info... with so many plugins/dependencies in a typical Gulp pipeline, its difficult to get a feel for which library would solve a given problem! In my case I'm already using through2 but had no idea I should have been giving it a closer look! Ugh streams are hard. Thank you for the detailed example!